How to have Nginx mirror a proxied WebSocket connection?
I have an Nginx server set up as a WebSocket proxy. The server has the following configuration:
location /websocket/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:50007;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

This works because when a client establishes a WebSocket connection to Nginx at location /websocket/, the WebSocket server on 192.168.1.10 successfully receives data over the WebSocket connection on port 50007.
Also, when I change the proxy_pass line to be proxy_pass http://172.16.2.7:20002;, the WebSocket server on 172.16.2.7 successfully receives data over the WebSocket connection on port 20002.
Now I want to set up mirroring so that when a client establishes a WebSocket connection to Nginx, Nginx proxies the connection to both 192.168.1.10 and 172.16.2.7. I modified the Nginx configuration to the following:
location /websocket/ {
    mirror /websocket-mirror;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:50007;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
location = /websocket-mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://172.16.2.7:20002$request_uri;
}

With that configuration, the WebSocket server on 192.168.1.10 still receives data over the WebSocket connection on port 10001, but the WebSocket server on 172.16.2.7 does not receive the mirrored WebSocket connection on port 20002. I ran tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 20002 on 172.16.2.7, and it prints the following when the WebSocket client establishes a connection Nginx, so that means Nginx is sending something over to 172.16.2.7, although the WebSocket server on 172.16.2.7 doesn't seem to be getting the connection:
19:42:20.183101 IP 192.168.1.10.59108 > 172.16.2.7.20002: Flags [S], seq 2129395342, win 64240, options [mss 1410,sackOK,TS val 3588603611 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:42:20.183156 IP 172.16.2.7.20002 > 192.168.1.10.59108: Flags [S.], seq 2013514890, ack 2129395343, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2348973749 ecr 3588603611,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:42:20.183577 IP 192.168.1.10.59108 > 172.16.2.7.20002: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3588603612 ecr 2348973749], length 0
19:42:20.183639 IP 192.168.1.10.59108 > 172.16.2.7.20002: Flags [P.], seq 1:320, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3588603612 ecr 2348973749], length 319
19:42:20.183658 IP 172.16.2.7.20002 > 192.168.1.10.59108: Flags [.], ack 320, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2348973749 ecr 3588603612], length 0
19:42:20.184806 IP 172.16.2.7.20002 > 192.168.1.10.59108: Flags [P.], seq 1:168, ack 320, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2348973751 ecr 3588603612], length 167
19:42:20.184833 IP 172.16.2.7.20002 > 192.168.1.10.59108: Flags [P.], seq 168:245, ack 320, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2348973751 ecr 3588603612], length 77
19:42:20.184878 IP 192.168.1.10.59108 > 172.16.2.7.20002: Flags [.], ack 168, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3588603613 ecr 2348973751], length 0
19:42:20.184878 IP 192.168.1.10.59108 > 172.16.2.7.20002: Flags [.], ack 245, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3588603613 ecr 2348973751], length 0
19:42:20.184937 IP 192.168.1.10.59108 > 172.16.2.7.20002: Flags [F.], seq 320, ack 245, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3588603613 ecr 2348973751], length 0
19:42:20.185004 IP 172.16.2.7.20002 > 192.168.1.10.59108: Flags [F.], seq 245, ack 321, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2348973751 ecr 3588603613], length 0
19:42:20.185054 IP 192.168.1.10.59108 > 172.16.2.7.20002: Flags [.], ack 246, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3588603614 ecr 2348973751], length 0

Then I changed the Nginx configuration to the following:
location /websocket/ {
    mirror /websocket-mirror;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:50007;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
location = /websocket-mirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://172.16.2.7:20002$request_uri;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

With that configuration, both of the WebSocket servers on 192.168.1.10 and 172.16.2.7 receive the WebSocket connection and are able to print out the HTTP headers, however, when they call the recv() Python function to get the data sent over the connection, the following error occurs on both servers:
connection handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 963, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1033, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1108, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 1165, in read_frame
    frame = await Frame.read(
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/framing.py", line 68, in read
    data = await reader(2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py", line 706, in readexactly
    raise exceptions.IncompleteReadError(incomplete, n)
asyncio.exceptions.IncompleteReadError: 0 bytes read on a total of 2 expected bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/server.py", line 236, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self)
  File "/home/azureuser/websocket-server.py", line 10, in handler
    data = await websocket.recv()
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 568, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/websockets/legacy/protocol.py", line 939, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent

Any idea why mirroring a proxied WebSocket connection using Nginx is not working?
